# Реализация отображения Popup в QSystemTrayIcon

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui

**Хочу реализовать поведение иконки системного трея** по аналогии с иконкой панели управления громкостью Windows 10. То есть при клике на иконке, всплывает окно, при повторном клике на иконку - сворачивается; если при развернутом окне кликнуть в область вне окна виджета, окно сворачивается.

Если не применять функцию `trigger`, то при сворачивании окна, развернуть его не получится.

При реализации сворачивания/разворачивания на `лкм` по проверке текущего состояния окна возникает проблема, что проверка производится после отпускания `лкм`, а само окно сворачивается при нажатии (видимо, особенность реализации Popup), возникает конфликт.

Можно ли исправить данную проблему? Ранее сталкивался что можно у виджета переопределить методы на нажатие и отпускание клавиш мыши, но тут не нашел, или плохо искал. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QCheckBox, QSystemTrayIcon, \
    QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QMenu, QAction, QStyle, qApp
import PyQt5.QtCore
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(600, 130))
        self.setMaximumSize(PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(600, 130))
        self.setWindowFlags(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.Popup)
        screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
        screen_size = (screen_geometry.width(), screen_geometry.height())
        win_size = (self.frameSize().width(), self.frameSize().height())
        x = screen_size[0] - win_size[0]
        y = screen_size[1] - win_size[1]
        self.move(x, y)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.85)
        self.setWindowTitle("System Tray Application")
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        grid_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Application, which can minimize to Tray", self), 0, 0)

        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_ComputerIcon))
        self.tray_icon.activated.connect(self.trigger)
        self.tray_icon.show()

    def trigger(self, reason):
        if reason == QSystemTrayIcon.MiddleClick:
            qApp.quit()

        elif reason == QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger:
            self.setVisible(not self.isVisible())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: `если при развернутом окне кликнуть в область вне окна виджета, окно сворачивается.` это же поведение `QMenu`. Вот пример `QMenu` с пользовательским виджетом в `tray`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/220478468c12d8b781ac49e4a7143087589351ad/currrent_job_report/main.py#L194

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то добавив флажок `self.fl`
вы получите желаемый результат.

Обратите внимание, я немного сместил расположение приложения
и поправил наследование `QGridLayout`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, \
                            QWidget, QCheckBox, QSystemTrayIcon, \
                            QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QMenu, QAction, QStyle, qApp
import PyQt5.QtCore


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(600, 130))
        self.setMaximumSize(PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(600, 130))

        self.setWindowFlags(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.Popup)

        screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
        screen_size = (screen_geometry.width(), screen_geometry.height())
        win_size = (self.frameSize().width(), self.frameSize().height())
        x = screen_size[0] - win_size[0]
        y = screen_size[1] - win_size[1]
        self.move(x, y)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.85)
        self.setWindowTitle("System Tray Application")
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(central_widget)             # - (self) !!! + central_widget
#        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)                # -
        grid_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Приложение, которое можно свернуть в трей", self), 0, 0)

        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self) # ??? self
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_ComputerIcon))
        self.tray_icon.activated.connect(self.trigger)
        self.tray_icon.show()

        self.setGeometry(500, 570, 600, 130)                  # +        
        self.fl = False                                       # + <<<-----<

    def trigger(self, reason):
        if reason == QSystemTrayIcon.MiddleClick:
            qApp.quit()
        elif reason == QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger:
#            self.setVisible(not self.isVisible())            # -

# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            if not self.fl:
                self.show()
            else:
                self.hide()
            self.fl = not self.fl   
        elif reason == 1:
            self.fl = False

    # Если кликнуть и отпустить мышу (не важно, левую, правую или среднюю) 
    # по окну приложения - оно закроется.
    # Если у вас другие планы, уберите этот метод.
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.hide()
        self.fl = False
# + ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, получается наиболее похоже, если убрать `mouseReleaseEvent`; единственное, если главное окно активно и нажать `лкм` не на значок, а на область вне главного окна, то `self.fl` не обновляет статус, и приходится два раза нажимать на значок чтобы затриггерить вызов главного окна.

Comment: Подскажите, есть ли возможность отследить было ли предыдущие нажатие `лкм` на самом значке, или в иной области? Либо можно поправить как-то по другому?